# jQuery pagination will not rebind after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I have a search results screen where i display a number of rows and then use the [jPages plugin](http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/) to paginate the same in a very simple manner. This works great. The code to do this is below

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function paginate() {
            $('div.holder').jPages({
                containerID: 'searchResults',
                perPage: 5
            });
        }

        $(function(){
            paginate();
        });
  </script>
```

quick primer on jPage plugin - I have a table where the body has the identifier 'searchResults' and then I have a div at the bottom of the table called 'holder'. The jQuery plugin automatically iterates through all the  elements and creates pages with the actual pagination placed in the 'holder' div element.

Now when the user clicks a particular checkbox on the screen, an AJAX call is made to refresh the search results and the table is repopulated with the contents of that AJAX call. This also works fine - the code of the same is below -

```
$(function() {
    $('.dark-checkbox').click(function(e) {
        var data = $('#search-form').serialize();
        refreshSearchResults(data);

        paginate();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });     
});

function refreshSearchResults(data) {
    if (data.length==0) { 
        return;
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("search-results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","candidate_search_results.php?"+data,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}
```

As you can see, I have tried re-generating the pagination based on the search results refresh as one of the last steps in the click handler.

The pagination is regenerated but just as one page - in other words, the plugin doesn't seem to be really working right and creating the right pagination flow. I have tried placing the call to 'repaginate' in other sections of the code as well and it doesn't seem to be working either. Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing incorrectly? Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it - replaced non jQuery AJAX method with a true jQuery AJAX piece of code. Basically, I replaced the refreshSearchResults() method with the below piece of code - this did the trick

```
$(function(){
    $('#search-form').find('.dark-checkbox').click(function(){
        alert($('#search-form').serialize());
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:$('#search-form').attr('action'),
            data:$('#search-form').serialize(),
            success:function(response){
                $('#search-results').html(response);
                paginate();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It probably would have worked in the original example if you'd called `paginate` after updating the content in the `onreadystatechange` callback.  +1 for using `$.ajax` if you're using jQuery anyway, though.

Comment: thank you - I didnt think of that option. will keep this in mind for future reference